# Android: are there any benefits to using different density images besides IQ control?

Tags: android, image

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620416/android-purpose-of-using-images-with-different-pixel-density) but am still uncertain of the value of different DPI targets.
Doesn't supporting multiple density images add to the .apk file size, whereas just using high-res images offers a solution for all screens (using automatic scaling)? There's still only one binary for users to install unless one limits the app to phones and tablets, so the smaller the file, the better.

Is downscaling of images dependent on hardware implementation and sometimes messy nearest-neighbour resampling is used, or can I be confident it'll be a bilinear resampling no matter the hardware, which is fine for photos? And is there a significant performance gain in providing suitably presized bitmaps?

It seems to me that the extra meg or two of asset files may be more cost than gain.

Answer (score 1):

I was toying with the same thing myself. Eclipse makes it easy to add every resolution as you can simply add an Android Icon Set which automatically creates the right sizes for you, it makes the app a bit bigger. Apparently XHDPI is only supported from Froyo (API 8) so if you're going to support before that you need to include HDPI. Also older devices, the rescaling doesn't look as nice and it's slower but the new devices, there's no real difference. At the Google IO I recall them saying it's okay just to use the XHDPI if you're targeting at and above API 8.